# Text file downloaded from R/Python command has different encoding than manually created one

Tags: python, r, text, encoding

I am retrieving a text file (namely, a satellite's Two-Line Element) from either a Python or R script, to ingest it in a command line executable.

```r
# R
download.file(url = "https://www.celestrak.com/satcat/tle.php?CATNR=02866",
              destfile = "./TLER.txt")
```

```python
# Python
import requests

tle = requests.get("https://www.celestrak.com/satcat/tle.php?CATNR=02866").text
tleFile = open("./TLEpy.txt", "w").write(tle)
```

The output is identical, whether in UTF-8 or hexadecimal encoding:

```
    LES-5                   
    1 02866U 67066E   21257.85304255 -.00000086  00000-0  00000-0 0  9991
    2 02866   1.8776 258.9950 0053870  16.8258  45.8627  1.09425410112039

    4c45 532d 3520 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
    2020 2020 2020 2020 0d0a 3120 3032 3836
    3655 2036 3730 3636 4520 2020 3231 3235
    372e 3835 3330 3432 3535 202d 2e30 3030
    3030 3038 3620 2030 3030 3030 2d30 2020
    3030 3030 302d 3020 3020 2039 3939 310d
    0a32 2030 3238 3636 2020 2031 2e38 3737
    3620 3235 382e 3939 3530 2030 3035 3338
    3730 2020 3136 2e38 3235 3820 2034 352e
    3836 3237 2020 312e 3039 3432 3534 3130
    3131 3230 3339 0d0a
```

This text output makes the command line executable hang. However, when I manually copy-paste the 3 lines, paste it in a new text file, and save it (using Ubuntu's default text editor or Sublime Text), the executable runs perfectly. I decided to have a look at the text manually pasted, and its hexadecimal encoding is the following:

```
    4c45 532d 3520 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
    2020 2020 2020 2020 0a31 2030 3238 3636
    5520 3637 3036 3645 2020 2032 3132 3537
    2e38 3533 3034 3235 3520 2d2e 3030 3030
    3030 3836 2020 3030 3030 302d 3020 2030
    3030 3030 2d30 2030 2020 3939 3931 0a32
    2030 3238 3636 2020 2031 2e38 3737 3620
    3235 382e 3939 3530 2030 3035 3338 3730
    2020 3136 2e38 3235 3820 2034 352e 3836
    3237 2020 312e 3039 3432 3534 3130 3131
    3230 3339 0a
```

It seems the end-of-line characters are different (`0d0a` vs `0a`), and other changes I do not grasp. All the files' ownership and permissions are identical, so the encoding seems to be the only difference.

**Question**: how could I make the Python/R commands encode the file in a similar manner than when manually creating it? The issue seems to mostly lie with end-of-line encoding.

Note: for the interested, the executable in question is this one: https://github.com/anoved/Ground-Track-Generator

Comment: Can you give us some more information? The file that is being downloaded uses UTF-8 but your question is regarding hexadecimal? Is that correct?

Comment: The file is intended to be encoded in plain text/UTF-8. The issue is that the downloaded text file is not correctly read/parsed by an executable, while the text file manually copy-pasted and saved runs fine. 

Since the difference between the two seem to lie in the end-of-line character encoding, I'm looking at a way to correctly encode end-of-line characters right from the download.

Comment: Are you just working with text files? Are you just using R/Python to download the file?

Comment: No, the download part is followed by data processing (for context: these text files allow me to plot a satellite track on Earth surface, track on which I do some geographic data manipulation). My code can be implemented either in R or Python, hence my attempt with both.

Comment: I'm sorry, there just isn't enough context here. It seems that there is likely an issue with how the data is processed. However, the only code you really show here is how you download the data.

Comment: How I process the data afterwards is not relevant, because I cannot even get there. The issue is: downloading and saving a text file via these commands encodes end-of-line character differently than when manually copying and pasting the text via a text editor. This is what I identified as the issue preventing me from ingesting these text files into an executable when downloading them via Python/R. I am just looking at a way to have the download encode end-of-line the same way as manually copy/pasting it.

Comment: The download seems to work fine for me though. I also tried downloading the file using `curl` instead of R or Python. All the downloads match the format of 3 lines on the website (https://www.celestrak.com/satcat/tle.php?CATNR=02866).

Comment: Use `guess_encoding` from the` readr` package to correct the file's encoding. Read https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/encoding.html. Then use `read_delim` to read the files and set the` locale` parameter appropriately. This should solve your problem.